# I've got the following two SQL tables (in MySQL):

Tags: proc-sql

I've got the following two SQL tables (in proc SQL):

```
A
+----+------+--------------+
| id | age  | 
+----+------+
| 1  | 10   |
+----+------+
| 2  | 20   |
+----+------+
| 3  | 30   |
+----+------+
| 4  | 40   |
+----+------+

B
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 1  | 
+----
| 2  |
+----+
| 3  |  
+----+
```

The desired output would be: How do I get this output in proc sql

```
+----+------+
| id | age  | 
+----+------+
| 4  | 40   | 
+----+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A  NATURAL LEFT JOIN B
WHERE B.id IS NULL
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c47983/1)**

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from A
where not exists(select * from b
                 where B.ID=A.Id)
```